# How to clone the List correctly in the constructor?

Tags: java, collections, constructor, linked-list, copyonwritearraylist

The constructor takes a List as parameters, this List needs to be filled with the same elements, for example "1" and cloned 7 times, assign the result to different collections, so that then 7 methods would process each of their lists.

constructor call:

```
public Class1 {
    public Class2 arrayList = new Class2(new ArrayList<>(10000))
    public Class2 linkedList = new Class2(new LinkedList<>())
    public Class2 cowList = new Class2(new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>())
}

public Class2 {

    private List<Integer> list;
    private List<Integer> list2;
    private List<Integer> list3;
    private List<Integer> list4;
    private List<Integer> list5;
    private List<Integer> list6;
    private List<Integer> list7;

    public Class2(List<Integer> list) {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.add(1);
        }

        this.list = list;
        this.list2 = list;
        this.list3 = list;
        this.list4 = list;
        this.list5 = list;
        this.list6 = list;
        this.list7 = list;
    }

    method1(){
        // list - doSomething...;
    }

    method2(){
        // list1 - doSomething...;
    }

    method3(){
        // list2 - doSomething...;
    }    

    method4(){
        // list3 - doSomething...;
    }

    ...

}
```

Each method performs a specific operation on its list. Depending on the constructor being called, the list is - `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

My code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: `this.list = list;      this.list2 = list; .......   ` All those 7 lists refer to the same memory location.

Comment: please tell me how to properly clone them inside this constructor? I cannot understand this moment, so that each sheet has its own memory block

Comment: @Bronskidev use `this.list2 = new ArrayList<>(list);` to initialize all those 7 lists

Comment: @GauthamM and if this constructor is called with LinkedList or CopyOnWriteArrayList? is this even possible? can I use one constructor for 3 different collections?

Comment: @Bronskidev you can check the type of list using `instanceof`, Then, write a method (you may name it copy) that would return `new ArrayList<>(list)` or `new LinkedList<>(list)` or any other required type based on conditions like `if(list instanceof ArrayList)`. Then in the constructor just call `this.list4 = copy(list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below statements, all your lists point to the same memory location and hence any operation on the list would be visible to all of list1 to list7.

`this.list = list;    this.list2 = list;    this.list3 = list;`

Instead you need to generate a new arraylist containing the elements of the input list using the appropriate list constructor which accepts a `Collection` as the argument.

Since the input could be of any `List` type, you could make use of `instanceof` to check the type of input and invoke the appropriate constructor.

**NOTE: You are only creating a new list. So changes to the original list won't be reflected on those seven lists. BUT the objects contained in the list are still referenced in the new lists as we are not cloning the object. We are just creating a new list with the same objects. SO if you were using `List<SomeObject>` instead of `List<Integer>`, were `SomeObject` is mutable, then any operations on the objects would be reflected on every list. This is not applicable to this specific question as it uses immutable `Integer` objects.**

```java
private static List<Integer> copy(List<Integer> input) {
    if(input instanceof ArrayList) {
        return new ArrayList<>(input);
    } else if (input instanceof LinkedList) {
        return new LinkedList<>(input);
    }
    // others
    ...............
    ...............

}
```

Now invoke this method in your class' constructor.

```java
this.list = copy(list);
this.list2 = copy(list);
this.list3 = copy(list);
```

You could also replace the for loop at the beginning with the below:

```java
Collections.fill(list, 1);
```

But with the current code, all inputs are empty and hence the `size` of every list you are passing would be `0`. Hence no filling of elements would take place (using `for` loop or `Collections.fill`)

`new ArrayList<>(10000)` does not update the size of the arraylist. It only initializes the backing array.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785568/how-to-clone-the-list-correctly-in-the-constructor/69793199#comment123371307_69793199) too.

Comment: This code should only be seen as an academic exercise, to show that it is possible. But developers should never use it. Just because the caller passes a `LinkedList` into the constructor, we don’t have to create a `LinkedList` in our code. We can not enumerate all `List` implementations of the world in this constructor and it would be pointless to try. The class should consider what it actually needs (almost never a `LinkedList`) and just use that type. E.g. `new ArrayList<>(input)` if a mutable list is needed or `List.copyOf(input)` for an immutable list.